# display a spark data frame in a json format instead of table

Tags: pyspark

I want to see few rows of a dataframe. But i want to see it in json format.

Is it possible. Because `df.show()`  prints in table format. I have lot of columns. I feel can it be printed in json format

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to visualize how the final dataframe will look like if you write it to console. The best way would be to create a temp directory. Write few rows of data to that directory, read that directory file by file. Here's an example.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import os


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)


data1 = [

[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-01",200],
[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-02",210],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-01",150],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-02",160],
[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-01",200],
[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-02",210],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-01",150],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-02",160],
[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-01",200],
[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-02",210],
]

columns =["member_id", "age", "gender", "date", "cost"]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns)

print("dataframe printed")
df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)



import tempfile
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

## a large dataframe so only limiting to 6 rows
df1.limit(7).write.format("json").mode('overwrite').save(temp_dir)

files = [os.path.join(temp_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(temp_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(temp_dir, f))]

print(files)
print()

for file in files:
    if file.split("/")[-1].startswith("part"):
        with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            print("file being printed", file)
            line_content = f.readlines()
            final = "".join(line_content)
            print(final)
```

Output :

```
dataframe printed
+---------+---+------+----------+----+
|member_id|age|gender|date      |cost|
+---------+---+------+----------+----+
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-01|200 |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-02|210 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-01|150 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-02|160 |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-01|200 |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-02|210 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-01|150 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-02|160 |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-01|200 |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-02|210 |
+---------+---+------+----------+----+

['/tmp/tmptset62u3/_SUCCESS', '/tmp/tmptset62u3/._SUCCESS.crc', '/tmp/tmptset62u3/part-00000-b481e6a1-f4af-4f21-88c5-c7e9e4134030-c000.json', '/tmp/tmptset62u3/.part-00000-b481e6a1-f4af-4f21-88c5-c7e9e4134030-c000.json.crc']

file being printed /tmp/tmptset62u3/part-00000-b481e6a1-f4af-4f21-88c5-c7e9e4134030-c000.json
{"member_id":1,"age":35,"gender":"Male","date":"2023-10-01","cost":200}
{"member_id":1,"age":35,"gender":"Male","date":"2023-10-02","cost":210}
{"member_id":2,"age":28,"gender":"Female","date":"2023-10-01","cost":150}
{"member_id":2,"age":28,"gender":"Female","date":"2023-10-02","cost":160}
{"member_id":1,"age":35,"gender":"Male","date":"2023-10-01","cost":200}
{"member_id":1,"age":35,"gender":"Male","date":"2023-10-02","cost":210}
{"member_id":2,"age":28,"gender":"Female","date":"2023-10-01","cost":150}
```

Comment: So you mean there is no other way than to first say as json and then print it

Comment: Display format of dataframe which you get on console with `df.show` is fixed. But output format which you get when write in json, csv, parquet, is not fixed.